# React create an array queue of objects to be sent once connection is available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, jsx

I have the following JSX code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';
import serialize from 'form-serialize';

var a = [], b= [];

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            email: '',
            university: '',
            degree: '',
            candidates: []
        }

        this.setFirstName = this.setFirstName.bind(this);
        this.setEmail = this.setEmail.bind(this);
        this.setUniversity = this.setUniversity.bind(this);
        this.setDegree = this.setDegree.bind(this); 
    }

    setFirstName(name) {
        this.setState({
            firstName: name
        });
    }

    setEmail(email) {
        this.setState({
            email: email 
        });
    }

    setUniversity(university) {
        this.setState({
            university: university
        });
    }

    setDegree(degree) {
        this.setState({
            degree: degree
        });
    }

    setCandidates(candidates) {
        this.setState({
            candidates: candiadtes
        })
    }

    getSingleInputValue(e) {

        if(e.target.getAttribute('name') == 'name'){
            this.setFirstName(e.target.value);
        }

        if(e.target.getAttribute('name') == 'email'){
            this.setEmail(e.target.value);
        }

        if(e.target.getAttribute('name') == 'university'){
            this.setUniversity(e.target.value);
        }

        if(e.target.getAttribute('name') == 'degree'){
            this.setDegree(e.target.value);
        }

    }

    submitForm(e) {
        var token = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0].getAttribute("content");
        var form = document.querySelector('.form');

        e.preventDefault();

        var singleCandidate = serialize(form, { hash: true });

        if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("candidates"))) { // checks if there is one or more values
            a.length = 0;
            a.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("candidates")));

            b.push(singleCandidate);

            var temp = a.concat(b);

            // localStorage.setItem("candidates", JSON.stringify(temp));
            // console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("candidates")));
        }

        else {
            localStorage.setItem("candidates", JSON.stringify(singleCandidate));
            console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("candidates")));
        }


    render() {
        let isVisible = this.props.visibility ? "" : "hide-form";

        return(
            <form className={"form " + isVisible}>
                <input 
                    placeholder="John Green" 
                    type="text" 
                    name="name"
                    onChange={this.getSingleInputValue.bind(this)} />

                <input 
                    placeholder="Email" 
                    type="text" 
                    name="email"
                    onChange={this.getSingleInputValue.bind(this)} />

                <input 
                    placeholder="University"
                    type="text" 
                    name="university"
                    onChange={this.getSingleInputValue.bind(this)} />

                <input 
                    placeholder="Degree"
                    type="text" 
                    name="degree"
                    onChange={this.getSingleInputValue.bind(this)} />

                <button onClick={this.submitForm.bind(this)}>enter</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

I am trying to save some data into the local storage and create some sort of queuing system, so that once the connection is back, I can submit that data with AXIOS.

Inside "submitForm(e)":

- if it's the first time (inside else) I populate localstorage with  the first object (singleCandidate)
- otherwise I am trying save data into an array and combining it with a new array based on the existing values inside the localstorage.

However, I am getting an array inside an array:

[image]

The aim is that if there is no connection and the user updates the form, for each form submitted an array gets populated with the data and stored in the localstorage.

How can I for every form submission store data in a single object and update an array to be pushed to localstorage and being retrieved once connection is back?

Comment: You haven't asked any question ;)

Comment: I did now, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Ok. So you don't know how to achieve that or you're having problem with object (array in your case) being stored in wrong format?

Comment: My idea was to use 2 array (one for every new form submission and the second for existing data inside the local storage to combined). However the end result as you can see in the screenshot attached is wrong, I am supposed to get one array of objects. I am getting an array inside an array.. The format is wrong. Thank you

Comment: I can only guess, but looks like your `singleCandidate` variable is an array. Please `console.log` it and check.

Comment: It's an object  coming from "var singleCandidate = serialize(form, { hash: true });" https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-serialize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152514/discussion-between-jimmyweb-and-alex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a little private chat I'm posting an updated implementation of `submitForm` method that works for Alex:

```
submitForm(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var token = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0].getAttribute("content"); 
  var form = document.querySelector('.form'); 

  var singleCandidate = serialize(form, { hash: true }); 
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem("candidates") 

  if (fromStorage) { 
    var parsedFromStorage = JSON.parse(fromStorage) 
    parsedFromStorage.push(singleCandidate) 
    localStorage.setItem("candidates", JSON.stringify(parsedFromStorage)) 
  } else { 
    localStorage.setItem("candidates", JSON.stringify([singleCandidate])); 
  } 
}
```